# Chrome extension: Replace HTML before loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a question about how to change web pages with a Chrome extension.

After reading some info I think the question is how to manipulating the DOM. 
Let's say I open www.stackoverflow with Chrome and want to replace the following line of code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and replace it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

My question is not if it's a smart thing to do, but how to do this?

Comment: I believe it's too late to change it after it has been loaded. You could replace the element, but the script from googleapis will have been requested already.

Comment: @MetalFrog Chrome extensions are not the same thing as a website's javascript. "You don't, and I'm glad you can't" is a good attitude for site javascript, but questionable for something which a user must manually install. Don't like what an extension does to your browser? Don't install it. Did you accidentally install it? Uninstall it. But when you apply this attitude to core API features that aren't enabled by default (i.e. you must install the extension), you end up with less powerful tools, which directly affects your ability to solve problems. Something to think about.

Comment: @L0j1k The tool is not less powerful because it's prohibiting code injection by default. When you need to take exorbitant effort to go above and beyond the pale to reach the desired outcome -- that in no way limits the use case of the *vast* majority of the user base, mind you -- there is no problem.

Comment: What it seems like you just said is that as long as people don't use a certain feature often, it's not a problem to make it impossible to use, as in the case of a Chrome extension replacing HTML before the page loads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to modify you manifest's file run_at string.

In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/

Comment: Page returns 404